# How to use more parameters in help-ballon grails-plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, help-balloon

I try to use more of the parameters but could not get it working with

```
<g:helpBalloon title="foo" content="bla" useEvent="['mouseover']" />
```

should result in

```
<script type="text/javascript"> new HelpBalloon({ title: 'foo', content: 'bla', useEvent: ['mouseover'] }); </script>
```

but useEvent="['mouseover']" seems not to be recognized?!

as seen on 
http://www.beauscott.com/examples/help_balloons/doc/examples.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at the code for that plugin](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/grails-plugins/grails-help-balloons/trunk/grails-app/taglib/org/grails/plugins/helpballoons/HelpBalloonTagLib.groovy?r=HEAD), it looks like it doesn't do the useEvent bit